# Text does not show up in sencha touch app

Tags: android, ios, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to display static text in sencha touch app but it is not showing that text. Perhaps the reason is that I am `extending` from `Ext.Panel` rather than `Ext.tab.Panel`. But I do not want to display tabs at all. Here is my code

Main.js

```
Ext.define('HB.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'main',

requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar'
],

config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'search'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Search.js

```
Ext.define('HB.view.Search', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'search',

config: {
    title: 'Search',
    layout: 'fit',
    scrollable: true,
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    styleHtmlCls: 'searchpage',
    html: ['<h1>Welcome to MyApp</h1>'].join(''),

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Search Page',
            docked: 'top'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

And I added the views in app.js like follow

```
views: ['Main','Search'],
```

With my above code I cannot see this text `Welcome to MyApp` on that page. Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: are you able to see `titlebar` on `Search.js` view with `title` "Search Page"?

Comment: When I `extend: Ext.tab.Panel` instead of `extend: Ext.Panel` then it shows `Welcome to MyApp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following `config` to your `Search.js` view :

```
style:'height:'+(Ext.getBody().getHeight())+'px;',
```

Or

**EDIT :**

Here problem is with `Height` only, you need to assign `Height` to your `formpanel` declaration when you are adding this to your `parent panel`.

```
fullscreen: true,
height:Ext.getBody().getHeight(),
```

**Height** and **Style** properties are not **deprecated** with **sencha 2.1** :

[Height](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-height)

[Style](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-style)

Thanks.

Comment: It gives me this message `style is deprecated as a property directly on the Component. Please put it inside the config object, and retrieve it using "this.config.style"`

Comment: @x4ph4r put this `stype` property under `config: {...}` block.

Comment: @x4ph4r which sencha sdk version you are using?

Comment: @x4ph4r also try to add this property to your config `fullscreen: true,`.

Comment: I am using sencha touch 2.1

Comment: @x4ph4r see edit I have posted links which shows `Height` and `Style` are not `deprecated` so you can use them.